# ¿Por que el arreglo no respeta el tamaño que le doy por teclado y salen números que yo no puse?

Tags: c++, array, bucles

Estoy aprendiendo c++ y estoy haciendo un programa que tiene que pedir cualquier numero al usuario, yo puse un limite de 50 números y solo tiene que imprimir los primeros 10  pares números.
El problema es que cuando imprimo solo imprime los números 5 y cuando no lleno el arreglo completamente y lo acabo antes colocan un caracter después de los números que coloque en el arreglo aparecen números que yo no puse .

```
 
using namespace std; 
 
int main()
{

  int size = 50;        //tamaño del arreglo
  int cout = 0;         //variable para saber la porcion de array que vamos a imprimir
  int arregloImpares[size];         //arreglo
        
  std::cout << "introduce los elementos "<< "\n";
  //ciclo para pedir los elementos dentro del arreglo
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (std::cin >> arregloImpares[i])  // comprobar si el tipo de valor que se coloca de tipo entero
    {
    //si es tipo entero sigue
      cout++;
    }
    else
    {
    //si no es de tipo entero deja de pedir mas numeros
      break;
    }
  }
//ciclo para imprimir solo los elementos pares del arreglo  
std::cout << "Elementos del array "<< "\t";
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if(arregloImpares[i]% 2 == 0)
    {
       std::cout << arregloImpares[i] << "\t";
    }
   
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bueno los números que vez y que tú no pusiste es lo que está en memoria en ese momento ya que arreglo no lo inicializar a 0.

Comment: ¿Entonces  hay una forma de quitar esos números?

Comment: Puedes inicializar la memoria o no leer memoria que no inicializaste.

Comment: ¿Pero cómo puedo hacer que no lea esos numero?@Pablochaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que ir almacenando sólo los números que sean pares:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
 
int main()
{
  int size = 10;        //tamaño del arreglo
  int n = 0;         //variable para saber la porcion de array que vamos a imprimir
  int numero;
  int arregloImpares[size];         //arreglo
        
  std::cout << "introduce los elementos "<< "\n";
  //ciclo para pedir los elementos dentro del arreglo
  while (n < size)
  {
    if (std::cin >> numero)  // comprobar si el tipo de valor que se coloca de tipo entero
    {
      //si es tipo entero sigue
      if (numero % 2 == 0)
      {
        // Almacenar el numero si es par
        arregloImpares[n] = numero;  
        n++;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //si no es de tipo entero deja de pedir mas numeros
      break;
    }
  }
  //ciclo para imprimir solo los elementos pares del arreglo  
  std::cout << "Elementos del array "<< "\t";
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    std::cout << arregloImpares[i] << "\t";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

La idea es ir almacenando los primeros 10 números pares, mientras la ejecución no se interrumpa.

Para interrumpir el ingreso de números se debe ingresar una letra, no un número decimal (si ingresas un número decimal, va a entender que la parte del número antes del punto es el último número ingresado).

Saludos.

Comment: Ok, pero el otro problema es que el programa solo debe imprimir los 10 primeros números pares ¿entonces cómo puede limitar al for para que haga eso?

Comment: Modifiqué el código para que almacene los 10 primeros números pares ingresados